# Dropdown fills with same values

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with re-filling dropdown. I have a code to fill dropdown over `fecth`. It makes 3 options in select tag . Now i have a button that works as "refresh server". `On click` it calls the `fetch function` again. Im trying to `on click remove`  all the options in select tag and refill it. This is my code

```
  for (let i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      select.remove(i);
    }
    setTimeout(fetchUrl, 1000);
```

The problem i have is that i deletes the previous 3 options but it makes 6 options with same values.It should be something like this:

```
Option1  Pump1
Option2  Pump2
Option3  Pump3
```

but the result i get is this.

```
Option1  Pump1
Option2  Pump2
Option3  Pump3
Option4  Pump1
Option5  Pump2
Option6  Pump3
```

My fetch

```js
fetch(url)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
      opt = data;
      console.log(data);
      opt.forEach((item) => {
        console.log(item);
        options.push({
          v: item.name,
          t: item.name,
        });
      });
      let selectTag = $("#node-input-options")[0];
      let elem = $("#node-input-filter");
      //                                                                                         Loop through the options and for every element create <option></option>
      for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        let value = options[i].v;
        let text = options[i].t;
        $("#node-input-options").append(
          $("<option></option>").attr("value", value).text(text) //For every element in the select tag append appropriate value and text (   <option value="#">#</option>    )
        );
      }
```

Comment: pls add more code(full context). from this probably no one help you.

Comment: looks like you have not clear/remove your previous items. But need more details to check it out

Comment: The problem it that when i press the btn and check the console, the options are gone, but then fetch function is called and it returns the previous objects + adds same 3 new objects

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your code, you

1. Need to not create unnecessary arrays
2. Clear the select, .html() will do that
3. Append only the fetch data - right now you keep appending to options array

---

```
fetch(url)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    $("#node-input-options")
      .html(`<option>Please select</option>`)
      .append(
         data
          .map(({name}) => `<option value="${name}">${name}</option>`)
          .join("")
      )
  });
```

Comment: Why do u have the result array tho? I dont want no hardcoded values . I want to get data from some api.

Comment: how can i send my code? It says text too long